# Open a form to a specific tab

Tags: ms-access, vba, tabcontrol

When a button is pressed I want to open a form at a specific tab.

on click event I have:

`DoCmd.OpenForm "MAIN_USER_FORM", acNormal, , "App_Ref = " & Me.App_Ref, , , "PRB"`

On the open event of the form I have:

```
If Me.OpenArgs = "PRB" Then
   Me.PRB_Validation.SetFocus

End If
```

PRB_Validation is the name of the tab in the MAIN_USER_FORM I wish to open.

I've searched forms, I just can't get it to work any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the tab control works on indexes. lets assume, the tab you are trying to open is at 4th number. Then I would do like this: YourTabControlName.Value = 3. It will activate that tab.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to check the `OpenArgs` in the form's `OnLoad` event, and set the TabCtontrol's value to the index of the page you want to show, like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If OpenArgs = "PRB" Then
        TabCtl0.Value = PagePRB.PageIndex
    End If
End Sub
```

I made [an example accdb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52900980/StackOverflow/SO18401954.accdb) to show the complete setup.

Answer (score 1):

In case if anyone is looking for code where you have a button on another form and want to open Main form from that and also take user to a particular Tab.

```
Private Sub YourButton_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_YourButton_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "YourFormName"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
    Forms![YourFormName]!YourPage.SetFocus

Exit_YourButton_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_YourButton_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_YourButton_Click

End Sub
```